# Suds Python Array Response

Tags: python, arrays, object, soap, suds

Using Python 2.7 and SUDS. How would I print just URL from these arrays/objects? I'd like to be able to pick any of the arrays/objects (such as URL) and just print an entire list of them instead of/or in addition to the response already being given from the server.

Here is my request:

```
from suds.client import Client
import logging



# Specify Login Information
developer_key = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxxxx'
account_guid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx'
sku = ['A30938', 'B84727']

# Specify URLs
wsdl_url = 'https://api.channeladvisor.com/ChannelAdvisorAPI/v6/InventoryService.asmx?WSDL'
service_url = 'https://api.channeladvisor.com/ChannelAdvisorAPI/v6/InventoryService.asmx'

# Initialize client.
client = Client(wsdl_url, location = service_url)

# Pass login information
login = client.factory.create('APICredentials')
login.DeveloperKey = developer_key
login.Password = password
client.set_options(soapheaders=login)

# Initiate request
for i in sku:

    result = client.service.GetInventoryItemImageList(account_guid, i)

    # Print the result to the screen.
    print result
```

And here is the results:

```
(APIResultOfArrayOfImageInfoResponse){
   Status = "Success"
   MessageCode = 0
   ResultData = 
      (ArrayOfImageInfoResponse){
         ImageInfoResponse[] = 
            (ImageInfoResponse){
               PlacementName = "ITEMIMAGEURL1"
               FolderName = None
               Url = "d3t71aa9ase5oz.cloudfront.net/12801479/images/bear_white.jpg"
            },
            (ImageInfoResponse){
               PlacementName = "ITEMIMAGEURL2"
               FolderName = None
               Url = "d3t71aa9ase5oz.cloudfront.net/12801479/images/bear_black.jpg"
            },
      }
 }
(APIResultOfArrayOfImageInfoResponse){
   Status = "Success"
   MessageCode = 0
   ResultData = 
      (ArrayOfImageInfoResponse){
         ImageInfoResponse[] = 
            (ImageInfoResponse){
               PlacementName = "ITEMIMAGEURL1"
               FolderName = None
               Url = "http://d3t71aa9ase5oz.cloudfront.net/12801479/images/m89851.jpg"
            },
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the items and get the attribute you want. Something like:

```
for item in response:
    for data in item.ResultData:
        print data.Url
```

Comment: I'm getting:                                                AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Url'